# Unable to get/set a stringArray with the hackage COM package in Haskell

Tags: haskell, com

I'm using the IDL compiler Hdirect and the latest com package on hackage.
I'm using GHC 7.4.1.

I want to communicate with Clearcase (version 7).

I'm able to do all kind of operations (getting element, version, label, ...)
BUT if I try to lock a label, I shall give an StringArray variant as argument.

My code looks like this:

```
ccLab # createLockCCLT "" (0::Int) [""]
```

ccLab is my label and [""] is my attempt to provide a StringArray.
The code compiles fine but I get a run-time error:
list method not implemented ...

`createLockCCLT` method is generated by Hdirect:

```
-- Locks this label type
createLockCCLT :: (Variant a1, Variant a2, Variant a3)`
               => a1
               -> a2
               -> a3
               -> ICCLabelType a0
               -> IO ()
createLockCCLT comment obsolete exemptUsersStringArray =
  method0 "CreateLock"
          [ inDefaultValue (inVariant "") inVariant comment
          , inDefaultValue (inInt32 0) inVariant obsolete
          , inVariant exemptUsersStringArray
          ]
```

I already try to build a safe array myself but without success.
It seems as well a list is not a good candidate because a variant array
is able to contain elements of different types.

Has someone an idea ?